# Add focus to video to disable unwanted space bar scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, scroll

In a video player I always want the spacebar to pause. This is not happening.

The problem- Without clicking first, the page behaves unexpectedly. Instead of pausing the video, the space bar makes the page scroll down.

My attempt to solve - When the video player is clicked I've noticed display property on one of the many divs associated with the video player changes from `none` to `block`. I added this to see if this would make the page behave properly

```
  if(videoPlayer.style.display === "none"){
    videoPlayer.style.display = "block"
}
```

It changes the class but does not alter the pages behaviour. This was just a shot in the dark at what might toggle the video, and doesn't work.

How can I figure out which properties are changed when I click the page?
So I can figure out what is bringing the player into focus. 
And so that I can write something to make the page load with the video in focus (I guess using a browser extension?) Or, just plain `how to do I solve this problem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to work out what is happening when you click the page, you can use your browser's developer tools.

e.g In chrome right click on the page > Inspect > Ensure you are on the elements tab along the top.

Then use the "Select an element in the page" tool in the top left of the dev tools (or Ctrl+Shift+C) to select the element on the page you want to see the onclick properties for.

In the dev tools either near the bottom or towards the right you should see a tab called "Event Listeners". Click on that to see what the element responds to from the user. There will probably be one there called "click"; click on this to see more info.

---

Secondly, if you want to stop the space bar from scrolling the page, just use the following:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.key == " " && e.target == document.body){
    e.preventDefault;
    //Spacebar pressed
    //Place function here to pause the video
  }
}
```

Here `e.preventDefault` is the line that stops the page from scrolling.

Comment: I added this in the console- 
`document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
if(e.key == " "){
console.log('test')
    e.preventDefault;
}`
});
The log works but the prevent default does not. I removed the `&& document.body` as it didn't fire at all with that. What is wrong here?

Comment: Edit- I forgot the brackets! `e.preventDefault()`